# Vertica SQL: Disregard rows, based on two conditions

Tags: sql, vertica, multiple-conditions

I need a where condition that considers to following for an entire table:

If a 0 exists for an ID (in column d) then exclude everything that is >0, if 0 does not exist, but exists a row where d = a then exclude everything before that..

In Example (Case 1) I want to disregard rows 1 & 2, in Example 2 (Case 2) I want to disregard rows 1,2,& 3.

Currenty I have: `where d <= 0 or d = a`) but in Case 1 this also returns row nr 2, which I do not want.

| row nr | ID | d | a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 180 | 78 |
| 2 | 1 | 78 | 78 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 78 |
| 4 | 1 | -67 | 78 |
| 5 | 1 | -121 | 78 |

| row nr | ID | d | a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 180 | 148 |
| 2 | 2 | 171 | 148 |
| 3 | 2 | 170 | 148 |
| 4 | 2 | 148 | 148 |
| 5 | 2 | -67 | 148 |
| 6 | 2 | -121 | 148 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This becomes a bit more complex to do than what you expected. You will have to involve a nested query with an OLAP function to detect that each row in a partition ( defined by the value of `id`) belongs to a partition of which at least one row has a value of 0 for `d`, and then, outside of that nested query, filter for that fact, and the value of `d` being 0 or greater. That's case 1.

In the other case, you use the same nested query to ascertain that you use only rows with **no row** with a value of 0 for `d` in the partition, and from there, the easiest way is to use Vertica's `MATCH()` clause to filter out the pattern of rows that consists of : a row with a `d` equal to `a`; zero, one or more occurrences of any row following, which I describe, in the query, with the pattern: `(d_equal_a anyrow*)` .

Here goes:

```
WITH
-- YOUR INPUT, don't use in query
indata(row_nr,ID,d,a) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,180,78
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,78,78
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,0,78
UNION ALL SELECT 4,1,-67,78
UNION ALL SELECT 5,1,-121,78
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,180,148
UNION ALL SELECT 2,2,171,148
UNION ALL SELECT 3,2,170,148
UNION ALL SELECT 4,2,148,148
UNION ALL SELECT 5,2,-67,148
UNION ALL SELECT 6,2,-121,148
)
-- end of your input, real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
min_abs_d_eq_0 AS (
-- nested query with OLAP expression returning Boolean
  SELECT
    *
    , (MIN(ABS(d)) OVER (PARTITION BY id) = 0) AS min_abs_d_eq_0
  FROM indata
)
,
case1 AS (
  SELECT
    row_nr
  , id
  , d
  , a
  , 'no match clause' AS event_name -- these are based on the 
  , 0 AS pattern_id                 -- MATCH clause coming from 
  , 0 AS match_id                   -- the next CTE, "case2"
  FROM min_abs_d_eq_0
  WHERE min_abs_d_eq_0 AND d <= 0
)
,
case2 AS (
  SELECT
    row_nr
  , id
  , d
  , a
  , event_name()
  , pattern_id()
  , match_id()
  FROM min_abs_d_eq_0
  WHERE NOT min_abs_d_eq_0
  MATCH (
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY row_nr
    DEFINE
      d_equal_a  AS d = a
    , anyrow    AS true
    PATTERN p AS (d_equal_a anyrow*)
  )
)
SELECT * FROM case1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM case2
ORDER BY id,row_nr;
-- out  row_nr | id |  d   |  a  |   event_name    | pattern_id | match_id 
-- out --------+----+------+-----+-----------------+------------+----------
-- out       3 |  1 |    0 |  78 | no match clause |          0 |        0
-- out       4 |  1 |  -67 |  78 | no match clause |          0 |        0
-- out       5 |  1 | -121 |  78 | no match clause |          0 |        0
-- out       4 |  2 |  148 | 148 | d_equal_a       |          1 |        1
-- out       5 |  2 |  -67 | 148 | anyrow          |          1 |        2
-- out       6 |  2 | -121 | 148 | anyrow          |          1 |        3
```

Comment: I read your requirements wrong. Indeed, rows number 1 and 2 should be disregarded, not selected. Correcting the query ... should be better now.

Comment: Thanks for the start! But if I see correctly, from case 1 the row where 0 = 78 should not be excluded from the dataset.

Comment: For `id` = 1, my query now, after the correction, returns `row_nr` 3, 4 and 5. In Row with `row_nr` = 3 and `id` = 1, `d` is 0 and `a` is 78. Is that the row you mean?